# What's a better way of writing this loop?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, loops, controller

Any thoughts on how to build a better loop for this rails controller?

I get a little lost on logic loops sometimes, so I resort to neanderthal code.

```
def index

 @step1_status = current_user.steps.pluck(:step1).first
 @step2_status = current_user.steps.pluck(:step2).first
 @step3_status = current_user.steps.pluck(:step3).first
 @step4_status = current_user.steps.pluck(:step4).first
 @step5_status = current_user.steps.pluck(:step5).first
 @step6_status = current_user.steps.pluck(:step6).first
 @step7_status = current_user.steps.pluck(:step7).first
 @step8_status = current_user.steps.pluck(:step8).first
 @step9_status = current_user.steps.pluck(:step9).first

 if @step9_status == true
  @task = Task.limit(1).order('sort_id ASC').where.not(:sort_id => ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'])
 elsif @step8_status == true
  @task = Task.limit(1).order('sort_id ASC').where.not(:sort_id => ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8'])
 elsif @step7_status == true
  @task = Task.limit(1).order('sort_id ASC').where.not(:sort_id => ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7'])
 elsif @step6_status == true
  @task = Task.limit(1).order('sort_id ASC').where.not(:sort_id => ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'])
 elsif @step5_status == true
  @task = Task.limit(1).order('sort_id ASC').where.not(:sort_id => ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'])
 elsif @step4_status == true
  @task = Task.limit(1).order('sort_id ASC').where.not(:sort_id => ['1', '2', '3', '4'])
 elsif @step3_status == true
  @task = Task.limit(1).order('sort_id ASC').where.not(:sort_id => ['1', '2', '3'])
 elsif @step2_status == true
  @task = Task.limit(1).order('sort_id ASC').where.not(:sort_id => ['1', '2'])
 elsif @step1_status == true
  @task = Task.limit(1).order('sort_id ASC').where.not(:sort_id => '1')
 else
  @task = Task.limit(1).order('sort_id ASC')
 end

end
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What's the point in plucking the same row 9 times (9 DB calls!) just to get the different single columns from it? And why didn't you make that `stepN` monstrosity into a seaprate table (i. e. normalize it) so you can actually use step numbers as data, instead of "resorting to neandertal code" fiddling with column names? Is this intentionally done by design, or is this a design oversight?

Comment: What loop? There's no loop here.

Comment: Haha, I know. It's shit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should be the same.

First try

```
@step_status = []
9.times do |n|
  @step_status << current_user.steps.pluck("step#{n+1}").first
end

highest_step = @step_status.rindex(true)
if highest_step
  @task = Task.order('sort_id ASC').where.not(sort_id: (1..(highest_step+1))).first
else
  @task = Task.order('sort_id ASC').first
end
```

A bit more optimized and less code

```
highest_step = (1..9).to_a.rindex{|n| current_user.steps.pluck("step#{n+1}").first} + 1

@task = Task.order('sort_id ASC')
@task = @task.where.not(sort_id: (1..(highest_step))) if highest_step
@task = @task.first
```

Only 2 DB calls

```
pluck_array = (1..9).map{|n| "step#{n}"}
highest_step = current_user.steps.pluck(pluck_array).first.rindex(true) + 1 
#the + 1 accounts for the 1 being at index 0 through 9 at index 8

@task = Task.order('sort_id ASC')
@task = @task.where.not(sort_id: (1..(highest_step))) if highest_step
@task = @task.first
```

A bit easier to read (though a bit longer)

```
step_array = (1..9).to_a
pluck_array = step_array.map{|n| "step#{n}"}
highest_index = current_user.steps.pluck(pluck_array).first.rindex(true)
highest_step = step_array[highest_index]

@task = Task.order('sort_id ASC')
@task = @task.where.not(sort_id: (1..(highest_step))) if highest_step
@task = @task.first
```

Comment: this edit not only minimizes the code, but also short circuits the database hits after the highest true value

Comment: Thinking about it, you could do the entire first block in 1 DB call

Comment: The plus 1 still bothers me a little bit, simply because it isn't self explanitory